# A matrix simplification involving traces and norms.

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-decomposition, trace

Let $P = [P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_m]$ where $P_i$ is a $k$ dimensional vector.

I have this set $(u,w) \in \Phi$ and this matrix $D^{m\times m}$ and for each $(u,w) \in \Phi$ I have $D[u,w] = 1$, and now consider this summation:
$$
\sum_{u = 1}^{m}\sum_{w \in D(u)} ||P_{u} - P_{w}||^2
$$

Where $P_i$ is a $k$ dimensional vector, and $D(u)$ is a set where for each element of this set we have: $D[u,i] = 1$, for each $i \in D(u)$, consider matrix $C$ where except for $C_{uu} = C_{ww} = 1$ and  $C_{uw} = C_{wu} = -1$, all other elements are zero. How the above summation is equal to this:
$$
Tr(CP^TP)
$$

I am reading [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7321237/) paper and it is right in equation (4) and (5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obvious. For each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$, denote by $e_i\in\mathbb R^m$ the $i$-th vector in the standard basis, i.e. all entries of $e_i$ are zero, except that the $i$-th entry is one. Using the property of matrix trace that $\operatorname{tr}(XY)=\operatorname{tr}(YX)$ whenever both $XY$ and $YX$ make sense, we get
\begin{align}
\|P_u-P_w\|^2
&=(P_u-P_w)^T(P_u-P_w)\\
&=(e_u-e_w)^TP^TP(e_u-e_w)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\bigg(\underbrace{(e_u-e_w)^TP^TP}_X\ \underbrace{(e_u-e_w)}_Y\bigg)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left((e_u-e_w)(e_u-e_w)^TP^TP\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(CP^TP).
\end{align}

Comment: So obvious that you need several line breaks to write it down...

Comment: @Roland The derivation is indeed obvious. Anyone who has been exposed to one or two least square problems should be able to do it in mind without having to write down anything. You don't need an expert to do that. I wrote down the detailed steps only because the OP seems to be a complete beginner to this area.

Comment: My point is (and you seem to share it): Obiviousness depends on the audience. Starting an answer with, in essence, "The following is obvious to me." comes across condescending, to me at least.

Comment: @Roland Thank you. Then every author of a book on linear algebra is arrogant because they talk about "trivial solutions". No, "this is obvious" doesn't mean "it is obvious to ME", but "everyone with slight experience with this kind of stuffs should know the answer right away". It's a mere expression of expectation. I understand your point, but I think you are just assuming malice/hubris.